# styling Javascript with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, styling

I am having difficulty targeting the javascript elements that I want to code in CSS.

Here is my javascript code:

```
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]


function showDate(){
  var fullDate = new Date();    
  var d = fullDate.getDay();
  var m = fullDate.getMonth();
  var y = fullDate.getFullYear();

  var date = `${months[m]} ${d}, ${y}`;
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;

}

showDate();
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div id="date"><div>
```

I thought that to target it in CSS I would do

```
date{

{
```

but it is not working. I am trying to change the font and text size. How do I target elements to do so?

TYIA!

Answer (score 4):

```
date {
 /* css rules here */
}
```

would target a `<date></date>` element. If you are wanting to target an element with an ID, the proper selector is the `#` symbol. Your css would look like so:

```
#date {
  /* css rules here */
}
```

[Here is a reference to all of the CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and how to use them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To select elements by id, use a `#` before the id name, e.g.:

```
#date { 
    color: blue;
}
```

(This is true whether or not JavaScript is involved.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add selectors and span tags in order to customize your styles

Code example:

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]


function showDate(){
  var fullDate = new Date();    
  var d = fullDate.getDay();
  var m = fullDate.getMonth();
  var y = fullDate.getFullYear();

  var date = `${months[m]} <span class="day">${d}</span>, <span class="year">${y}</span>`;
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;

}
showDate();
```

```css
#date {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.day {
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.year {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```